# How to read and write utf_8 in python?

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, io

I have some non-ascii data in my python script .
python can handle them correctly but when I want to save them it gives an error. So I encode them with`str.encode()`and then write them to a file.
for reading the file and decoding the data I hadn't problem in python 2.7 using `str.decode()` - data from reading files are string - but in python 3.6 there isn't any `str.decode()` function and I got problem.

I couldn't find answer anywhere even in whole python official documentation.

Example code: ignore cases please im writing with phone at thistime

```
string="hello=سلام -in persian"
file=open("file.txt",'w+', encoding='utf-8')
file.write(string.encode())
# using file.write(string) raises an error
print(file.read())# if the whole string be in Persian prints sth like b'\xff\xa3....'
file.read().decode()# raises an error contains: str object doesn'have attribute decode
# here was my problem in updating from 2.7 to 3.6

file.close()
```

`

Comment: Without any code to look at, your question is difficult to answer. Most likely your problems will go away if you use the `encoding` parameter when opening files.

Comment: I,m going to update my question thank you for answer but didn't work by my approach to apply your help maybe other ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For python 3. You should write the `str` to file as `bytes` by using `str.encode()`, then open the file as write binary mode `open('filename.txt', 'wb')`. And when reading, read the file as read binary mode. `open('filename.txt', 'rb')` and use `bytes.decode()` to convert it back to `str`.

You can use this as an reference:

```
utfchar = '¶'
with open('filename.txt', 'wb') as fp:
    fp.write(utfchar.encode())

# and later:

with open('filename.txt', 'rb') as fp:
    utfchar = fp.read().decode()

assert utfchar == '¶'
```

Answer (score 2):

In Python 3 you can simply write the string:

```
with open('file.txt', 'w+', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write("hello=שלום in Hebrew")
```

Comment: ok no problem in this part , I get problem in loading and decoding the data in next part of code , thanks for the answer.